# wget times out when try to load website on the web-server

Tags: apache, networking, web, wget, lamp

I have a CentOS; LAMP web server and have finished 97% of development work. I can test my website anywhere on the LAN and can load correctly on different browsers from different machine.

However when I try wget on the web server, it is timing out for some reason. Please point me in the right direction for this as some functionality is not working the way it was designed because of this.

Thanks!

Comment: [root@www ~]$ wget --debug http://www-stg.nwtel.ca
DEBUG output created by Wget 1.14 on linux-gnu.

URI encoding = ‘UTF-8’
--2015-09-10 19:58:56--  http://www-stg.nwtel.ca/
Resolving www-stg.nwtel.ca (www-stg.nwtel.ca)... 199.85.228.40
Caching www-stg.nwtel.ca => 199.85.228.40
Connecting to www-stg.nwtel.ca (www-stg.nwtel.ca)|199.85.228.40|:80... Closed fd 3
failed: Connection timed out.
Releasing 0x0000000001e99610 (new refcount 1).
Retrying.

Comment: The server is still not open to the public as development is on-going. However wget from web server should still fetch the page. Correct?